# Why does Perl warn about "useless constant 1" when using bigint?

Tags: perl, perl-module, bigint, perlsyn

I was writing a module as part of my application when I noticed syntax check results in warning about *useless use of a constant (1)*. Why is that?

The constant is the obligatory `1` at the end of the module which is normally ignored by warnings as [`perldoc perldiag`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Useless-use-of-%25s-in-void-context) says:

> This warning will not be issued for numerical constants equal to 0 or 1 since they are often used in statements like
>
> ```
> 1 while sub_with_side_effects();
> ```

(There's probably an even better source for that. After all `1` at the end of files is totally desired and not to be warned about.)

But the warning is generated even for nearly empty modules if they `use bigint`.

```
package Foo;

use bigint;

1;
```

For this simple file syntax check produces the following warning:

```
$> perl -Wc Foo.pm
Useless use of a constant (1) in void context at Foo.pm line 5.
Foo.pm syntax OK
```

I could not find any reference to `bigint` and the warning message except [Put long hex numbers in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489970/put-long-hex-numbers-in-sqlite) but this doesn't really address my issue, I think.

My Perl is v5.14.4 on Cygwin with bigint 0.36.

Comment: [Sounds like a bug.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlbug.html)

Comment: Interesting find. I would guess it's because it's no longer '1' and thus ignorable, and is instead a special sort of '1'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two issues at hand here.

1. Why does `use bigint; 1;` warn in void context?
2. Why is the constant being executed in void context in the first place?

---

```
$ perl -c -we'1 while sub_with_side_effects();'
-e syntax OK

$ perl -c -we'use bigint; 1 while sub_with_side_effects();'
Useless use of a constant (1) in void context at -e line 1.
-e syntax OK
```

**Why does `use bigint; 1;` warn in void context?**

`use bigint;` installs a callback that's called when a constant literal is encountered by the parser, and the value returned by the callback is used as the constant instead. As such, under `use bigint;`, `1` is no longer truly just a simple `0` or `1`.

But you're not doing anything wrong, so this warning is spurious. You can work around it by using `()` or `undef` instead of `1`.

```
undef while sub_with_side_effects();
```

Unless I needed to use it throughout my code base, I would favour the following:

```
while ( sub_with_side_effects() ) { }
```

---

```
$ cat Module.pm
package Module;
use bigint;
1;

$ perl -c -w Module.pm
Useless use of a constant (1) in void context at Module.pm line 3.
Module.pm syntax OK
```

**Why is the constant being executed in void context?**

When Perl executes a *module*, Perl expects the module to return a scalar value, so Perl should be executing the module in scalar context.

However, you told Perl to compile the *script* `Module.pm`. When Perl executes a script, Perl doesn't require any values to be returned, so Perl executes the script in void context.

Using a module as a script can cause spurious warnings and errors, and so can passing `-W`. Test a module using as follows:

```
perl -we'use Module'
```

Actually, you shouldn't even need `-w` since you should already have `use warnings;` in the module. All you really need is

```
perl -e'use Module'
```

Answer (score 6):

-W instead of `use warnings;` in your module or checking modules with -c instead of `perl -MFoo -e0` can show spurious errors.  This is an example of the latter.

When you load a module normally, it *isn't* in void context, because it is checking that the result is true.

(Note that when I try it using 5.20.1, the -W also results in a spurious `overload arg '..' is invalid at /usr/share/perl/5.20/Math/BigInt.pm line 155`.)

Comment: Ironically, `perl -MFoo -we0` fails when testing bigint. `perl -we'use bigint;'` does the same without warning.

Comment: ah, you mean -Mbigint; yes, that is ironic.  `perl -MFoo -we#` works

Comment: Boggle ... real bugs, buglets or QA issue ??

Comment: @G.Cito: no, there is no bug here

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving here a workaround to avoid the warning: Defining a constant with value `1` before using `bigint`:

```
package Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;
use constant PACKAGE_END => 1;
use bigint;

PACKAGE_END;
```